# After fetching CSV file, my terminal output displays only last ~200 items

Tags: ruby-on-rails, csv, terminal

I am using https://github.com/tilo/smarter_csv gem to read my csv files. On the last line of my code I wrote `puts records` to see output from the function.

```
filename = 'db/csv/airports_codes.csv'
options = {
  :col_sep => 'tt',
  :headers_in_file => false,
  :user_provided_headers => [
    "id",
    "code",
    "city",
    "country",
    "country_code",
    "continent",
    "coordinate_x",
    "coordinate_y"
  ]
}
records = SmarterCSV.process(filename, options)

puts records
```

However there are so many outputs that my terminal displays only last ~200 items. How do I see others?

These are first 2 items displayed on top of the terminal.

```
{:id=>4564, :code=>"YEB", :city=>"Bar River", :country=>"Canada", :country_code=>"CA", :continent=>"North America", :coordinate_x=>"\\N", :coordinate_y=>"\\N"}
{:id=>4565, :code=>"YED", :city=>"Edmonton", :country=>"Canada", :country_code=>"CA", :continent=>"North America", :coordinate_x=>"\\N", :coordinate_y=>"\\N"}
```

I also want to note that it doesn't let me scroll above that. It acts like this is the first line in terminal and that there was nothing above it. I am using Ubuntu linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `records` is really just an array of objects, you can treat it as you would any array and use `slice` to break it up into viewable pieces.

```
records.slice(20, 10)
```

Will output 10 records, beginning at the 21st item

Obviously there are other alternatives, such as increasing the number of lines your terminal displays - but you should ask a specific question to http://unix.stackexchange.com - let them know which terminal you're using and which shell environment, etc and someone will help you.

Comment: In addition, on Ubuntu in terminal: Edit->Profile preferences->Scrolling->Unlimited checkbox